# Ember js : link to does not refreshes data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
 {{#each feed in model.feeddefinitions}}
            <tr>
                <td> {{#link-to 'feeddefinition' feed}}{{feed.displayTitle}}{{/link-to}} </td>
                <td> {{feed.url}} </td>
                <td> {{feed.type}} </td>
```

Route

```
Backoffice.FeeddefinitionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.get('store').find('feeddefinition', params.feeddefinition_id);
    }
});
```

Model

```
Backoffice.Feeddefinition = DS.Model.extend({
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    modifiedAt: DS.attr('date'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    link: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    disabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
    automaticallyAdded: DS.attr('boolean'),
    userAdded: DS.attr('boolean'),
    sections: DS.hasMany('sections', {async: true}),
    sectionfeeds: DS.hasMany('sectionfeeds', {async: true}),
    displayTitle: function () {
        return this.get('title') === '' ? 'No Title' : this.get('title');
    }.property('title')
});
```

Since I am using feed to link-to, it takes to the proper page but does not refreshes the data.

Note: I tried using this, for example 
                     {{#link-to 'feeddefinition' this}} but that points to parent id instead of feed id.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your `route` & `model`.

Comment: Hi Hasib, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a model directly to the `link-to` helper, which means that Ember is [going to skip the model hook entirely](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model). It assumes that if you're passing in a model explicitly, it already contains the data you want and doesn't need to be modified in any way. My suggestion would be to use the [afterModel](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel) hook to refresh the model.

```
afterModel: function(resolvedModel) {
    return resolvedModel.reload();
}
```

Comment: another choice if you want the force the model hook to do a new load is to only pass the `id` to the `link-to` helper. Something like `{{#link-to 'feeddefinition' feed.id}}`...